# Compare User input

Tags: mysql, sql, date, validation, date-comparison

I have a set of date (start date & end date) in DB, how to validate for duplicate date set between user input and DB. (Mysql)

i have try a few method but it only compare either start or end date only. not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following logic.

- Filter using between SQL command

  SELECT column_name(s)
  FROM table_name
  WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;

use the following logic:

- User registered new START DATE and END DATE
- Search for START DATE using BETWEEN into DATABASE
- Search for END DATE using BETWEEN into DATABASE
- If those values exists into ranges you can show duplicated message.

Regards
C.